# Rendering HTML to PNG / JPEG

Tags: php

I am looking for a php library or an unix shell tool to render a HTML page into a single png/jpg image.

Is there any?

Comment: have you searched on google? this is the first thing I found: [html2image](http://html2image-linux.smartcode.com/info.html). It does have conflicting information as to which OSs are supported, but nothing is stopping you from giving it a try.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "conversion" but rather use "rendering" word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a promising project.

It rendered the following code in 0.133 seconds using the webkit plugin.

```
<html>
<body>
<b><u>abc</u></b>
<table><tr><td>abc</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cutycapt/

Unfortunately it works **only for Windows**.

---

There is another webkit implementation using python.

**XServer-less webpage screenshot**

http://www.insecure.ws/2008/09/16/xserver-less-webpage-screenshot